# Как указать путь к локализации для тестового конфига

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[image: Структура приложения]

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как указать путь к бандлу в тестовом конфиге, пишет No message found under code 'userCreated' for locale 'en_US'

upd
Тесты видят этот бандл когда он в ресурсах лежит, если я указал путь как classpath:messages. А вот как сделать чтобы они видели его когда он в WEB-INF, который пакуется в war и который я и хочу тестировать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поместите переводы в папку `resources`.

Comment: @Tsyklop подскажите как быть, я собираю потом war-ник, если бандл лежит снаружи WB-INF то он не попадает в war и локализация не работает в приложении. А если у меня будет два разных бандла для теста и для war-ника, то мне не нравится, смысл в таких тестах.

Comment: Не правильно настроено веб приложении. Навскидку. Ибо все что есть в `webapp` должно быть в `war` файле

Comment: @Tsyklop так и есть, всё попадает в war, я не могу разобраться как путь для тестов указать до этого бандла с локализациями.

Comment: У тестов свои ресурсы. Тесты не попадают в собранный `war` архив.